# Laravel ANDROID “davibennun/laravel-push-notification”

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, laravel-5

I am using davibennun/laravel-push-notification in laravel framework for push notification, it worked well in iphone device but in android it gives

**"Unable to enable crypto on TCP connection gcm-http.googleapis.com"**

I also tried with

```
$deviceToken = "dxu8XvChIXg:APA91bEUASmBE_bpDzHlgvf9RZhLYE4W7ni5xeRZ-ze-QKE‌​-1uUFbTcWkGJ05GkbTWb‌​cU8tceA_rnUwDgBr8w46‌​cylkkvz9ORoCmdqSt8Ao‌​VviGRdQbcM1GtbDZqWdc‌​SpyJpZPSX2SRP";
$push = PushNotification::app('Androidpush');
$push->adapter->setAdapterParameters(['sslverifypeer' => false]);
$push->to($deviceToken)->send('Hello World, i`m a push message');
```

What I am doing wrong...??

Please suggest me if you already done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any error with the code you provided as compared with this [related issue](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/89). This could be an issue with how your http adapter is configured. Try to use the curl adapter, and/or make sure that the sslcapath is set to a valid location. Check this [thread](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification/issues/9) which one of the community also encounter the issue on Android devices.

> Change the
>   vendor/sly/notification-pusher/src/Sly/NotificationPusher/Adapter/Gcm.php
>
> ```
> Gcm.php -> public function getOpenClient(....){  
> $client->setApiKey($this->getParameter('apiKey'));
>
>     $new_client = new \Zend\Http\Client(null, array(
>                       'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket',
>                       'sslverifypeer' => false
>                   )); 
>     $client->setHttpClient($new_client);
>     return $client;
> }
> ```

Comment: `public function getOpenedClient()`
`{`
      `if (!isset($this->openedClient))` 
      `{`
            `$this->openedClient = new ServiceClient();`
            `$this->openedClient->setApiKey($this->getParameter('apiKey'));`
            `$newClient = new \Zend\Http\Client(
                null,
                [
                    'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Socket',
                    'sslverifypeer' => false
                ]
            );`
            `$this->openedClient->setHttpClient($newClient);`
        `}`
        `return $this->openedClient;`
    `}`